# Flutter - PopupMenuButton - add an item manually after adding items from a list

Tags: flutter, dart, popupmenubutton

I have a PopupMenuButton which displays items from a List.

```
List<Subject> subjects = [
  Subject(
    name: 'English',
    iconFile: 'english.jpg',
  ),
  Subject(
    name: 'Mathematics',
    iconFile: 'maths.jpg',
  ),
  Subject(
    name: 'Business Studies',
    iconFile: 'business.jpg',
  ),
];
```

Below is PopupMenuButton code where the list is used to generate the menu items:

```
child: PopupMenuButton<Subject>(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 115, 231),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              onSelected: _changeSubject,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return subjects.map((Subject subject) {
                  return PopupMenuItem<Subject>(
                    value: subject,
                    child: Text(subject.name),
                  );
                }).toList();
              },
            ),
```

This works as intended. Now I want to add another item "Sign Out" below "Business Studies" (as in this image link -> [PopupMenuButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJZXI.png)) and a divider between them. I don't want to add "Sign Out" to the subjects list. Is it possible to add another PopupMenuItem manually after all the generated items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpHX.png)

```
return PopupMenuButton(
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 95, 115, 231),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      itemBuilder: (context) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
        ...subjects
            .map((s) => PopupMenuItem(value: s, child: Text(s.name)))
            .toList(),
        const PopupMenuDivider(),
        PopupMenuItem(
          onTap: () {},
          value: "LogOut",
          child: const Text('LogOut'),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Your solution works the way I wanted UI-wise. But I can't have `onSelected: _changeSubject,` call.

Comment: ...subjects
            .map((s) => PopupMenuItem(
                  value: s,
                  child: Text(s.name),
                  onTap: _changeSubject(s),
                ))
            .toList(),    Just change like this

Answer (score 1):

`

```
Subject signOutSubject = Subject(
        name: 'Sign Out',
        iconFile: 'signOut.jpg',
    );
```

add to the end of the toList() function

```
 toList()..add(PopupMenuItem<Subject>(
                        value: signOutSubject,
                        child: Text(signOutSubject.name),
                      );)
```

`